# getting auto generated column Id =null in jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

getting id = null when I try to insert data in table  here is my create table syntax

```
CREATE TABLE query_builder (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  query_title varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  sql_query text NOT NULL,
  condition varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  output_fields varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  physician int(11) NOT NULL,
  creation_time timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  modification_time timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  discription text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY query_builder_physician_FK_idx (physician),
  CONSTRAINT query_builder_physician_FK FOREIGN KEY (physician) REFERENCES physician (Physician_Id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and entity for this is

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

public class QueryBuilder implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "query_title")
    private String queryTitle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "sql_query")
    private String sqlQuery;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "condition")
    private String condition;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "output_fields")
    private String outputFields;
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationTime;
    @Column(name = "modification_time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modificationTime;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "discription")
    private String discription;
    @JoinColumn(name = "physician", referencedColumnName = "Physician_Id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Physician physician;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name= "querybuilderId")
    private Collection<QueryBuilderCondition> queryBuilderConditionCollection;

    public QueryBuilder() {
    }

    public QueryBuilder(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public QueryBuilder(Integer id, String queryTitle, String sqlQuery, String condition, String outputFields, String discription) {
        this.id = id;
        this.queryTitle = queryTitle;
        this.sqlQuery = sqlQuery;
        this.condition = condition;
        this.outputFields = outputFields;
        this.discription = discription;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQueryTitle() {
        return queryTitle;
    }

    public void setQueryTitle(String queryTitle) {
        this.queryTitle = queryTitle;
    }

    public String getSqlQuery() {
        return sqlQuery;
    }

    public void setSqlQuery(String sqlQuery) {
        this.sqlQuery = sqlQuery;
    }

    public String getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public String getOutputFields() {
        return outputFields;
    }

    public void setOutputFields(String outputFields) {
        this.outputFields = outputFields;
    }

    public Date getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }

    public void setCreationTime(Date creationTime) {
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    public Date getModificationTime() {
        return modificationTime;
    }

    public void setModificationTime(Date modificationTime) {
        this.modificationTime = modificationTime;
    }

    public String getDiscription() {
        return discription;
    }

    public void setDiscription(String discription) {
        this.discription = discription;
    }

    public Physician getPhysician() {
        return physician;
    }

    public void setPhysician(Physician physician) {
        this.physician = physician;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<QueryBuilderCondition> getQueryBuilderConditionCollection() {
        return queryBuilderConditionCollection;
    }

    public void setQueryBuilderConditionCollection(Collection<QueryBuilderCondition> queryBuilderConditionCollection) {
        this.queryBuilderConditionCollection = queryBuilderConditionCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof QueryBuilder)) {
            return false;
        }
        QueryBuilder other = (QueryBuilder) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.medikm.entity.QueryBuilder[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

to store data in table i uset below code

```
 builder.setCondition(condition);
 builder.setCreationTime(new Date());
 builder.setDiscription(discription);
 builder.setOutputFields(fields);
 builder.setPhysician(new  PhysicianJpaController().findPhysician(physicianId));
 builder.setQueryTitle(title);
 builder.setSqlQuery(query);
 em.persist(builder);
 em.getTransaction().commit();
 em.close();
```

but above code give me an error

```
this is the error that i got when i try to persist
 [EL Warning]: 2016-06-29 14:22:03.749--UnitOfWork(900737)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseExceptionInternal Exception: om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, output_fields, discription, creation_time, modification_time, physici' at line 1Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO query_builder (query_title, sql_query, condition,output_fields, discription, creation_time, modification_time, physician) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)      bind => [adfdfafad, SELECT c.Case_Id, c.Age FROM case1 c, patient p, episode e, personal_medical_history pmh, reproductive_history rh WHERE( c.Disease_type = 2 AND c.Primary_Diagnosis_Dt <> '2016/06/22' OR c.Clinical_Stage = 'I'
 ) AND c.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id AND e.Case_Id = c.Case_Id
 AND pmh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id AND rh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
 GROUP BY c.Case_Id , "OR", ["ca.Age","ca.aortic_node_positive"], adffda, 2016-06-29 14:22:03.724, null, 200]Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.medikm.entity.QueryBuilder[ id=null ])javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872):org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, output_fields, discription, creation_time, modification_time, physici' at line 1
Error Code: 1064Call: INSERT INTO query_builder (query_title, sql_query, condition, output_fields, discription, creation_time, modification_time, physician) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) bind => [adfdfafad, SELECT c.Case_Id, c.Age FROM case1 c, patient p, episode e, personal_medical_history pmh, reproductive_history rhWHERE( c.Disease_type = 2 AND c.Primary_Diagnosis_Dt <> '2016/06/22' OR c.Clinical_Stage = 'I' ) AND c.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
 AND e.Case_Id = c.Case_Id AND pmh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
 AND rh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id GROUP BY c.Case_Id , "OR", ["ca.Age","ca.aortic_node_positive"], adffda, 2016-06-29 14:22:03.724, null, 200]Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.medikm.entity.QueryBuilder[ id=null ])at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:102)at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
```

please let me know if anything wrong done by me please help... Thank you

Comment: look at the SQL invoked for the INSERT (in the JPA provider log).

Comment: i have problem in query also i wnat to save this `query_builder (query_title, sql_query, condition, output_fields,physician,creation_time, modification_time, discription)` but query saves `query_builder (query_title, sql_query, condition, output_fields, discription, creation_time, modification_time, physician)` why query save this i don't have any idea please help

Comment: thank you neil for reply  ti have posted the whole error that i got

Comment: that SQL statement is being screwed up by "sql_query" whatever that is. Wherever "SELECT c.Case_Id, c.Age FROM case1 ..." is coming from. More than likely you have not shown us enough info ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys thank you so much for your help issue that I found is in my entity as I check I found that condition is reserved keyword in mysql and because of this I got this error

Answer (score 0):

Identity sequencing uses special IDENTITY columns in the database to allow the database to automatically assign an id to the object when its row is inserted. Identity columns are supported in many databases, such as MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase and Postgres. **Oracle does not support IDENTITY** columns but they can be simulated through using sequence objects and triggers.

If you are using Oracle, that might be the reason.

You can change this code

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

To this

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but still, i have the same problem i have use MYSQL database ... by using @GeneratedValue id is not getting null but this time it give sql syntax error..

Answer (score 0):

PhysicianJpaController() might not find a physician with "physicianId",so you might be trying to do this:
**builder.setPhysician(null);**
while you have also this:
**physician int(11) NOT NULL**

Comment: Thank you for answer i tried this also but still have the same error `Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.medikm.entity.QueryBuilder[ id=null ])
Exception is :-  42000`